# Javascript to write multiple values in a textarea

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. 
I have a simple asp .net page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="Demo.test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"/>
   <textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

On clicking Button1 the value entered in TextBox1 should be written into TextArea1. On the next click and so on the new values also should be added to the TextArea1 without removing the previous value.

Please help me to write a javascript function for the above scenario.

Comment: Where is your javascript?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Here, we expect certain standards and efforts from askers. I recommend you read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information. At the very least, we expect people to do a little [research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=use+javascript+to+populate+text+area&t=lm&atb=v72-6&ia=qa)

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery, you can do something like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Button1").on("click", () => {
      let oldContent = $("#TextArea1").html();
      $("#TextArea1").html(oldContent+$("#TextBox1").val());
    }); 
</script>
```

Not tested (no asp), but this is an idea. Good luck.